# SQL group all similar items with different suffix

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table logging all HTTP requests to my server, with the goal to know from time to time if some API takes too long, and to fix it.

Example:

```
uri             | rtime
---------------------
item/1          | 0.1
item/2          | 0.1
item/3          | 0.1
item/comments/1 | 0.2
```

So I made this query:

```
SELECT uri, COUNT(1) as count, AVG(rtime) as avgTime
FROM access_log
GROUP BY uri
ORDER BY avgTime DESC
```

The problem is, that it doesn't group for example `item/1` `item/2` and `item/3`

How can I group such that it will strip the last number after the `/`?

**EDIT:**

I want this to only strip numbers from the end, not strings

Comment: Will you always have a number at the end of the string? Can it also be multiple character numbers (10, 666)?

Comment: Indeed. Always numbers, can be any number (0 -> infi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use MySQL's `REGEXP` operator to identify uri's ending in a slash followed by a number.  In this case, we can substring off the trailing portion of the uri, otherwise use the full uri, when aggregating.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN uri REGEXP '^.*/[0-9]'
              THEN SUBSTRING(uri, 1, INSTR(uri, '/')-1)
              ELSE uri END AS uri,
       COUNT(1) as count,
       AVG(rtime) as avgTime
FROM access_log
GROUP BY CASE WHEN uri REGEXP '^.*/[0-9]'
              THEN SUBSTRING(uri, 1, INSTR(uri, '/')-1)
              ELSE uri END
ORDER BY avgTime DESC
```

Comment: Too powerful. will also work on strings, so for example `users/get` and `users/delete` will be grouped

Comment: It works. For some `uri`s it does `item/undefined` but it's ok because they are still grouped and I'll know how to read it.
Also, note that the MySQL equivalent to `CHARINDEX` is `LOCATE`

Comment: Another thing, it that this query works fine on a 17K rows table, but takes a few minutes on my 500K rows table

Comment: @Amit The best long term corrective action might be to redesign your table such that you don't such complex logic for simple queries.  For instance, you could add a new column `is_numeric` which would track whether the URI ends in a number.  Then, the above query would not need any regex, but rather just a simple substring operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX built in functions to get result :

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(uri,LEN(uri),INSTR('/',uri)), COUNT(1) as count,   
  AVG(rtime) as avgTime
  FROM #table
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(uri,LEN(uri),INSTR('/',uri))
  ORDER BY avgTime DESC
```

Comment: MySQL doesnt have a CHARINDEX function